# Breaking down the meaning of the phrase "En pelotas"

Tags: etimología

When I first heard the phrase *en pelotas* I had to ask what it meant. My informant was then unable to explain to me what it had to do with the object with which games are played nor with the sport often associated with the Basque region. Recently on seeing a headline where a performer complained that people kept asking her to pose *en pelotas* I started to search for more enlightenment.

In the DLE I discover that this is a separate derivation of [*pelota*](https://dle.rae.es/pelota?m=form)

> pelota2
>   De pelo.
>
> dejar a alguien en pelota, o en pelotas
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Quitarle o robarle todo lo que tiene.
>
> en pelota, o en pelotas
>
> 1. locs. advs. coloqs. Desnudo, en cueros. U. t. c. locs. adjs.

That obiously makes more sense since I know that *pelo* is skin. But where does the suffix fit in? Further search [reveals](https://dle.rae.es/-ote?m=form)

> -ote, ta
>   1. suf. U. para formar aumentativos y despectivos a partir de adjetivos y nombres. Bobote, grandote, angelote, marquesota.

Is this usage really *despectivo* and since it is a masculine noun why is it not *pelote* rather than *pelota*?

Incidentally I do not recommend an internet search for the phrase *en pelotas* if you are working in a public place.

Comment: I always thought that "en pelotas"  meant naked because obviously if you are naked people will see your balls. It has never occured to me that it has something to do with "pelo" plus a suffix, and I still don't think that is the case.

Comment: @DGaleano:  The expression "en pelota" appears in chapter XXII of the first part of [*El Quijote*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/clasicos/quijote/edicion/parte1/cap22/cap22_04.htm): "A Sancho le quitaron el gabán y, dejándole en pelota, repartiendo entre sí los demás despojos de la batalla, se fueron cada uno por su parte, con más cuidado de escaparse de la Hermandad que temían que de cargarse de la cadena e ir a presentarse ante la señora Dulcinea del Toboso." It's "en pelota", with "pelota" in singular, so it probably doesn't refer to Sancho's testicles.

Comment: @Charo excelente cita del Quijote. En Colombia (y al parecer Argentina) deterioramos la frase. Mucha gente dice "en pelota" pero muchos dicen "en pelotas". La respuesta parece tenerla Wikipedia en la sección "Origen del vulgarismo" https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_pelota

Comment: @Charo ....se me pasó... Aunque tu acertadamente citas que lo correcto es el singular la pregunta es por el plural. Por eso mi primer comentario.

Comment: @DGaleano: También en España decimos "en pelotas" o "en pelota picada". Según Wikipedia deriva de "piel", pero no tengo nada clara la fuente.

Comment: Aunque no siempre es así, me parece que el artículo de Wikipedia está bastante bien referenciado. La referencia del programa de televisión que dices, @Charo, solo se usa como ejemplo del uso en plural (*en pelotas* en lugar de *en pelota*).

Comment: @Gorpik:  Bueno, se supone que se pasa de "en pellote", a "en pelota" y, más adelante" a "en pelotas". Y creo que el programa de televisión es para poner un ejemplo de "en pelotas". Y "pellote" significa esto:  https://dle.rae.es/pellote?m=form.

Comment: Pero no sé de dónde sale que "en pelota" viene de "en pellote".

Comment: @Charo, ya, viendo lo que es un pellote se me hace raro, porque era una prenda externa. No sé si con el tiempo se empezó a usar el nombre para una prenda interior y de ahí ya la deriva a *pelota* por la similitud fonética.

Comment: @DGaleano in fact the DLE also mentions the singular in its definition. I have only heard and seen the plural though which is why I phrased my question about that form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Corominas, the expression *en pelota* took the meaning of "to be naked" due to the influence of the words *pelo* or *piel*. That would mean that *pelota* is not *pelo* plus a suffix, but *pelota* with a different meaning influenced by other words.

The expression is quite old, you can find it in texts from the 16th century:

> *Desde que el señor don Juan murió, que le hacía mucha merced, nunca tuvo suceso que fuese de hombre bien afortunado, y tanto, que era ya como proverbio su mala dicha. Estando, pues, un día con dolor en un pie, diciéndole un doctor que era gota, respondió:*
>
> *"Aunque pobre y en pelota,
>
>   mal de ricos me importuna,
>
>   porque al mar de mi fortuna
>
>   no le faltase una gota."*
>
> Juan Rufo, "Las seiscientas apotegmas", 1596 (Spain).

By that time, you could use *en pelota* with the meaning of "having nothing". You could also use *dejar a alguien en pelota* with the meaning of "stealing or robbing everything from a man and leave him with nothing". And of course you could be *en pelota*, completely naked. These expressions are already found in the *Autoridades* dictionary from 1737. The expression *en pelota* is found before that in a couple of dictionaries from 1705 and 1706.

The expression does not appear quite often in the CORDE, maybe around 20 cases per century. And it is not until the 20th century that the first cases of *en pelotas* appear. That could well be due to the fact that the expression starts to be linked to *pelota* as "ball", referring to one's balls, obviously the testicles. I bet that if you ask anyone what are the "pelotas" in the expression *en pelotas*, everyone will tell you they refer to the testicles.

The expression *en pelotas* is not despective, but just colloquial.

Comment: +1 ¡Qué gozo el tuyo de estar bañado en Corominas! Y por acá, abajo con las suposiciones vulgares que yo albergaba. Ahora podemos utilizar la expresión entre compañía culta, siempre en  singular: "pobre y en pelota".

Answer (score 2):

At least in Argentina 'en pelotas' means literally 'naked' with 'pelotas' being testicles. It can be understood in several ways:

- Someone is 'en pelotas' implying that he has no idea what he is talking about.
- You could also use as it is, to express that someone is naked.
- Or finally to say that someone is defenseless, figuratively he does not have anything to defend himself.

Hope I've helped you!

Comment: I agree. Same here in Colombia. As I said before in my comment to the question is just as simple as this. BTW Welcome Mati. +1

Comment: Same here in Chile, I've always heard the plural: "en pelotas"

Comment: Thank you for that but my original question was (1) is it despectivo, (2) why is it not pelote. Your answer does not sem to cover those.

Answer (score 0):

"En pelotas" means "nude". Pelotas refers to man's balls. However it is also used to emphasize a situation in which you are caught by surprise or a situation in which there is nothing you can do to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for that but my original question was (1) is it despectivo, (2) why is it not pelote. Your answer does not seem to cover those.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can tell about the use of *"en pelotas"* in Argentina.

Firstly, *pelo* does not mean "skin", *pelo* means "hair". *Pelo* and *pelota* are not related. The word is not formed by adding the *"ta"* suffix to the word *pelo*. *pelota* is a synonym for *bola*, which is: "ball".

Literally, *"en pelotas"* means: "in balls", i.e. "with balls (testicles) exposed".

The term *"en pelotas"* can be used in several ways, but I think that the most general word to describe its meaning is "*devoid*". The literal use means: "*devoid of clothes (so that my balls are exposed*)".

A very  important fact about the use of this expression is that what you are devoid of is often implicit. Thus, it can it can be used in an infinite number of situations to indicate the lack of something, for example: *"Se me rompió el auto, quedé en pelotas"* would mean something like: *"My car broke, I'm devoid of transport"*. Thus, it is never mentioned what you are devoid of; it is assumed that it is transport.

Its use is vulgar, not *despectivo*. However, it can be offensive. For example, if you say to an employee: *"siempre estas en pelotas"*, it is a bit offensive, because you are telling him he never knows anythying, or he is never aware of anything. However, if for example, you say *"No cobré, quedé en pelotas"*; it means that your were not paid and now you do not have any money (devoid of money). It is not offensive, but it is vulgar.

I think it is a very tricky expression, because it has an infinite number of uses. For example, if you say that a soccer player is *"en pelotas"* you mean that he is not paying attention to the game.

Lastly, the term *"en pelote"* is not correct. The word *pelote* does not exist. Also, we always use the plural *"en pelotas"* because commonly males have two balls (testicles).